Random spike in Add to Carts data in GA4
At least once a month for the last 6 months, there have been times when the add-to-cart count in the Ecommerce Purchases page (under Monetization) has randomly spiked between 10 million and 10 trillion.
I have tried to isolate the cause of the discrepancy and it seems to be coming from a tablet device.
Is there anyone who has experienced this and has a way to deal with it? Thanks.
Note: This data is eventually being pulled using GA4 API so this is why it's a major problem.
I have isolated the problem as best as i can but i can't find a solution.
